# Скольких минусов достаточно?

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-против

Недавно попался [плохой ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413814/178988). Поскольку решение в ответе плохое, поставил ему минус (и даже комментарий написал).

А потом задумался - ответ и так имел несколько минусов, и так было видно, что он плохой. Действительно ли стоило добавлять ещё минус? Пока раздумывал, и решил всё-таки не ставить, 5 минут уже прошло.

Если бы у ответа был рейтинг 0, то минус он бы однозначно заслуживал. Но заслуживал ли он ещё один минус, уже имея рейтинг -3 или -4? Есть ли какой-то момент, когда стоит сказать: "да, ответ плохой, но у него уже достаточно минусов"? Или надо всегда ставить минус?

Замечу, что из-за большого числа минусов автор может ответ и удалить. Т. е. хорошо бы не пересекать грань между "такой вариант есть и он ужасен" и удалённым ответом, до которого кто-то может додуматься сам и даже не узнать, что он плохой?

Comment: Вот пример: автор удалил вопрос с +1 (потом его восстановили другие участники). http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494011/181472

Comment: Я вообще редко минусую, только если ответ по теме, но совсем бредовый. Зачем зазря людей обижать (тем более анонимно)? Да и потенциальным читателям это полезно. Пусть больше думают или в комментариях допытываются, как все же лучше делать.

Answer (score 13):

Оценка всегда имеет смысл. Если на ответе 3 минуса, то я могу подумать, что он кому-то не нравится. Если на ответе 100 минусов, то я буду видеть, что ответ ненавидят всем миром.

Вы же всегда ставите плюс, если ответ вам нравится или он полезен? (Если нет, то за вами уже выехали.) Хотя с практической точки зрения всё равно, скорее всего выберут самый популярный ответ, если на нём много плюсов, или же он вовсе один.

Вот и с минусами то же самое.

Comment: Но ведь из-за большого числа минусов автор может ответ и удалить. Т. е. хорошо бы не пересекать грань между "такой вариант есть и он ужасен" и удалённым ответом, до которого кто-то может додуматься сам и даже не узнать, что он плохой?

Comment: @Qwertiy Автор может удалить ответ и с одним минусом, и вообще без оценок. Вы никогда не угадаете критериев качества конкретного автора. А если информация о неправильном ответе реально важна, то имеет смысл добавить её в правильный ответ с объяснением, почему так делать *не* надо.

Answer (score 5):

Я начинающий программист c# и регулярно задаю вопросы сообществу. Всегда получаю интересные ответы, которые помогают мне переосмыслить те или иные вещи и чуть-чуть вырости как специалисту. У меня сложилось впечатление, что **дух** stackoverflow - обучение тех кто не знает теми кто знает. 
Исходя из этого я думаю, что нельзя допускать ситуаций, когда ответы будут удалятся, но необходимо чтобы было очевидно - это **плохие** ответы.

Я думаю, что плохие ответы должны быть разделены на две группы:

1. Ответы, написав которые автор действительно **хотел помочь** задающему вопрос, но в силу собственного не знания ответ получился так себе.
2. Все другие плохие ответы.

Подводя черту, я думаю, что не очень правильно ставить сто или двести минусов парню, который хочет развиваться сам и помочь развиться другим людям. Даже если он сильно не угадал с решением. Считаю разумным, чтобы плохой ответ или нет определялось не количеством минусов, а через тревоги аудиторией компетентных специалистов по метке и при подаче тревоги необходимо писать комментарий почему так плохо либо давать ссылку на источник, где написано почему это - плохо.

Comment: IMHO: `"Даже если он сильно не угадал с решением"` -- так не годится. Если не знешь точно, что в данной ситуации надо делать именно так -- не пиши ответ (можно ограничиться комментарием).

Comment: @avp я говорю про ситуацию, когда человек думал, что знает как нужно, но оказалось, что его вариант плохой. Но изначально, я подчеркну, он думал, что у него отличный ответ.

Comment: Нет, минусы предназначены именно для того, чтобы показать, что ответ плохой. Но ведь нескольких минусов вполне достаточно, чтобы это показать.

Comment: В принципе до 5 минусов это нормально, да.
Я просто подумал, что когда парень хотел помочь и думал, что его решение правильное, а отхватил 20-30 минусов(и хорошо если не сто или двести), то это как-то не хорошо.

Comment: минусы имеют в 5 раз меньший вес. Поэтому пяти минусов для действительно плохого ответа - однозначно мало. Любой залётный плюс позволит не обращать внимания на эти ваши 5 минусов. В оценке качества контента важен каждый голос, если 80 участников считают ответ плохим - минусов должно быть 80.

Comment: @vp_arth, так цель же не участнику сделать суммарный отрицательный вклад в репутацию, а вопросу отрицательный рейтинг.

Comment: @Qwertiy Первичная цель - санитария, контроль качества. Негативное влияние минусов специальным образом нивелировано, чтобы избежать эффекта, который вы предлагаете(ограничиться пороговым значением минусов)

Answer (score 3):

> Замечу, что из-за большого числа минусов автор может ответ и удалить. Т. е. хорошо бы не пересекать грань между "такой вариант есть и он ужасен" и удалённым ответом, до которого кто-то может додуматься сам и даже не узнать, что он плохой?

Тут у нас вырисовывается проблема в понимании системы оценки качества контента.

Если вы считаете, что этот ответ не нужно удалять - т.е. он может быть полезен - вы ставите ему плюс. *В комментарии или правке упомяните о неприемлемости использования этого решения, если это необходимо.*

Минусы - показатель того, что ответ **сломан** и в текущем виде его стоит удалить (или исправить, но тогда вы будете иметь возможность отозвать минус).

---

Таким образом, наша система голосования является **саморегулируемой**. Плохой контент заминусовывается/удаляется(этому, кстати, способствует бонус в виде отката отрицательной репы), хороший остаётся.

Хороший контент - не синоним best practice.
Если в ответе указан bad way, о котором **необходимо** знать(с соответствующей рецензией) - он вполне себе заслуживает право жить, а следовательно и плюсов.

Comment: Вообще не согласен с этой позицией.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда почему у ответа нет минуса? :)

Comment: @alexolut, не заслужил)) Но плюса тоже нету)